# Metro or Modern UI?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-phone

In the previews of Windows 8 everyone was talking about `Metro` and since a few weeks ago it's called `Modern UI`.

Why the change and should I stop using the term `Metro`?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It's though to throw in a last vote, but the main decision that weighted is that you're replicating news, there's also no link to any Microsoft decision on this matter. Super User currently maintains the [tag:modern-ui] tag just in case, whereas Microsoft actually continued to use Metro as far as I can see and they've only renamed it in some places. So, unless you can back this up with actual facts and references this is unlikely to yield anything constructive; you can still edit both your Q&A and flag to reopen once you have added a verifiable source, thank you... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Modern UI` Style is the correct term for Windows 8 and Windows Phone since August 2012.

The german Metro AG  had threatened legal action against Microsoft for infringing on the ["Metro" trademark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_UI_%28design_language%29#Legal_issues). So Microsoft renamed `Metro` to `Modern UI Style`.

So maybe we should stop talking about `Metro`; but still it would have been better.